# How to mock a property with no setter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am trying to Mock an Interface.  The property i want to set "MockThisProperty" does not have a setter.  I cannot change the Interface source.  The error i get is

Previous method 'IThirdPartyInterface.get_MockThisProperty();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.

I've tried DynamicMock, Strictmock, partial mock, etc.

When I try  SetupResult.For(thirdParty.MockThisProperty = mockedValue) won't compile because there is no setter.

using the latest Rhino mocks with mstest

At a loss, here is the code...

```
        var stuff = _Mockery.Stub<Hashtable>();
        matchItem.Add(key, "Test"); 

        var thirdParty = _Mockery.Stub<IThirdPartyInterface>();
        SetupResult.For(thirdParty.MockThisProperty).Return(stuff);

        _Mockery.BackToRecordAll();


       //more code

        _Mockery.ReplayAll();

        Assert.IsTrue(MethodToTest(thirdParty));

        _Mockery.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) handles get-only properties. Just saying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var thirdParty = Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateStub<IThirdPartyInterface>();
thirdParty.Stub(x => x.MockThisProperty).Return("bar");
string mockPropertyValue = thirdParty.MockThisProperty; //returns "bar"
```

Comment: that works.  if i use _Mockery = new MockRepository()  _Mockery.Stub<>() like above then it throws an exception.  Anyone know why?

Comment: instantiating the mockrepository is more of an old way of setting up mocks and stubs and requires a lot of effort to manage recording and playback and such. using the static methods is the newer and preferred and much more automatic and predictable way.  you can get some unexpected results with the older way of dealing with things.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this post when trying to mock a property defined in an interface with no setter.

As I don't yet use Rhino and don't want another dependency than Moq, i found

`mockedWithMoq.SetupGet(x => x.PropertyWithGetterOnly).Returns("foo")`

will also do the work.